# How to send data with ajax when pressing enter

Tags: php, ajax

**form.php**

```
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="textalign: center;">    

    <label class="label" for="Fromdate">From Date</label>

    <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="textBox" name="fromDate" />

    <label class="label" for="Todate">To Date</label>

    <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="textBox" name="toDate" />

    <input type="submit" name="searchby" id="searchby" value="Search" class="buttonLarge" />

    <input type="submit" name="excel" value="Export To Excel" class="buttonLarge" />

</form>
```

**datediff.php**

```
<?php 
if(($_POST['searchby'] == 'Search')){

?>  
<script type="text/javascript">

        var fromDate = $("#datepicker").val();

        var toDate = $("#datepicker1").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "datediff.php",
                data: { fromDate,toDate },
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {                
                }

            });

</script>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: if you have `type="submit"` in your form then your form must submit automatically when pressing enter while your cursor is active inside an Input field

Comment: There two submit button search & second is Export to Excel I need When i press enter  then call ajax function

Answer (score 1):

- Wrong json { fromDate,toDate }.
- And yes it will submit if we press enter. For submitting it through ajax we have to prevent default functionality through event.preventDefault().

  ```
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
     search();
   }
  });

  $('#searchby').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    search(); 
  });

  function search()
  {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "datediff.php",
          data: { 'fromDate':$('#datepicker').val(), 'toDate':$('#datepicker1').val() },
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {                
          }

      });
  }
  ```

Comment: this code, on the page, where ever you will press enter ... form will be submit .... :(

Comment: When i select date ajax working fine same as when i enter name ajax call but value not display  name=':$('#FName').val(),fromDate':$('#datepicker').val(), 'toDate':$('#datepicker1').val()

Comment: @Umair - to prevent default action I have used event.preventDefault().

Comment: not event. because inside your function is e so you use e.preventDefault(); @HarishLalwani

Comment: Though it worked with event.preventDefault() but e.preventDefault() will be more correct. Thanks @aldrin27

Comment: @Harish When i am using given code 1 error has been generate "event is not defined" & ajax not working

Comment: use e.preventDefault() instead of event.preventDefault(). What browser are you using?

Comment: When i am using e.preventDefault() this function working fine Thank you so much

Comment: @aldrin27 can you please explain why this worked for me and not for bharat with event.preventDefault(). I used this code in my browser. I did not show any error 'event is not defined'. Using chrome Version 38.0.2125.101, assuming this is a browser issue.

Comment: One more think when i click on search button ajax not working when i press enter ajax work

Comment: Maybe the version of chrome or jquery you had @HarishLalwani

Comment: @bharat please upvote my comment if this works.
Try this:
In another line $('#searchby').click(function(e){ //Your ajax here });

Comment: @aldrin27 - sorry forgot to upvote. code edited for search button.